# Never getting attacked on clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have never been attacked on clash of clans. Why is this? And no, I have not just started.. I've been playing for a while I have a level 6 base with over a million in both gold and elixir and I'm not gonna lie my defenses are not that great. I have not once ever been attacked. I attack a lot of people.. And yet nobody has ever attacked me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If no one attacks you, thats a good thing. it means you dont lose loot to them.

Comment: I know it's a good thing not to be attacked, but I have NEVER been attacked with a lot of loot and poor defenses. I can't help but think I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I would rather say: What are you doing _right_? I also want to be in this situation!

Comment: Tell us your secrets? I have to save up at least 3 million gold or elixir to do anything nifty. Once I start nearing 2 million, the raids start rolling in.

Comment: Do you have a shield that is active?

Answer (score 1):

As many have said in the comments, this is an extremely good thing that all clashers look to accomplish.

Bases that do not get attacked usually have 3 things in common:

1. Great base design; looks scary to attackers
2. Possibly low loot in storages
3. Have an active shield/guard

If you really want to get attacked, I suggest pushing for trophies where higher level and experienced players are located.  These players will more likely attack your base even if there is a low loot count. This is because of the potential trophies being offered.

I do not know what your base looks like, but if it is a type of farming base it is doing its job correctly and very well.

If being attacked is your current goal in the game you could also make your base less protected (I would not be sure why this is your goal).